# How can I print an array and add a string to each item in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to write a short script that enters into a directory  prints out an array of the file names without an extension in one column and the in the next column adds the extension .fna. Then exits the directory to enter the next directory.

For eg I have the file names

```
ERR163030.fastq
ERR163031.fastq
```

and I would like the out put to be:

```
ERR163030 ERR163030.fna
ERR163031 ERR163031.fna
```

This is the code I have so far.

```
SRA_files=(P*)

# loop that picks each directory in the array
for i in "${SRA_files[@]}"
do
  #Go into directory 
   pushd "$i"; 
  #Make array  
   fastq_names=(*.fastq);
  # Exit directory 
  popd;
  # Print in main directory containing all the sub directories 
  printf "%s\n" "${fastq_names[*]%.*}" "${fastq_names[*]%.*}.fna" > "$i"_names.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to put the names with and without the extension on the same line, using `printf '%s\n'` doesn't work as intended (when passing the two forms as distinct arguments). That said, it's straightforward to just use a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nullglob                    ## avoid misbehavior when no matches exist
for dir in P*/; do                   ## / suffix ensures we only match directories
  fastq_names=( "$dir"*.fastq )
  for name in "${fastq_names[@]##*/}"; do
    printf '%s %s\n' "${name%.*}" "${name%.*}.fna"
  done >"${dir%/}"_names.txt
done
```

If we set up a test case as follows:

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/test.XXXXXX") && cd "$tempdir"
mkdir -p P123; touch P123/{ERR163030,ERR163031}.fastq
```

...output in `P123_names.txt` is, as expected:

```
ERR163030 ERR163030.fna
ERR163031 ERR163031.fna
```